# Validate email only if the string contains @

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Im trying make a program which only validates the email if contains @, my idea is to go trough all the string "email" using a for and in some point of the string is equal to @ it finish the string so a for inside a do while with a counter and when we counter is equal to one it finish is there any better solution to this?

I normally work in c++ so I'm not use to work on java/kotlin

Comment: Don't describe the code you're planning to write. Instead, write it, compile it, test it, iterate, and if you're really stuck, then ask a question, providing the code, if you have a concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a `String` contains a given character or another string using [`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html):

```
val email: String = "foo@bar.com"
val isValid: Boolean = email.contains('@')
```